# How do I loop my dice game program 3 times?

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a game that rolls 2 set of dice, three times in a row. It has the user guess a number between 2-12 just once. If that one guess matches any of the three rolls he/she wins, otherwise he/she loses. I have another class to display results and I have a counter for how many loops it's been through. It comes out 0 if the user correctly guessed it, otherwise it comes out as 1. I'm guessing the loop just loops once so if anyone can point out what I'm doing wrong to make it so it loops three times(and stopping if the user gets the answer right).

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


/**
 * @author Marcus
 *
 */
public class Dice {


    int randomDieNum1;//random number generator for dice
    int randomDieNum2;//random number generator for dice
    private final int   MINVALUE1 = 1, //minimum die value
                        MAXVALUE1 = 6;//maximum die value
    private final int   MINVALUE2 = 1, //minimum die value
                        MAXVALUE2 = 6;//maximum die value
    int userNum = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Guess a number between 1-12", "Guess a Number", 
            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE));//gets user input
    String result ; //results
    int start = 0  ; //counter to see how many turns were taken
public Dice()
    {
    for (int i = 1 ; i <= 3; i++) 
    randomDieNum1 = ((int)(Math.random()* 100) % MAXVALUE1 + MINVALUE1);
    randomDieNum2 = ((int)(Math.random()* 100) % MAXVALUE2 + MINVALUE2);
    int total = randomDieNum1 + randomDieNum2;
        if (randomDieNum1 + randomDieNum2 != userNum)
        {
            result =  "You did not guess the \n number correctly";
            ++ start;
         }
            else if (randomDieNum1 + randomDieNum2 == userNum)
         {
            result = randomDieNum1 + "+" + randomDieNum2 + "=" + total + "\n" +
            "You guessed the number correctly";
         }
         else 
        {
             result =  "You Did not guess the number correctly";
        }

        }
             public String get() //used in another class to display count
             {
                 String temp;
                 temp = "" + start;
                 return temp;
             }

        }
```

**EDIT** 
            Thanks guys. I added both suggestions and added a break to stop the loop after the user gets the answer right.
This is what it looks like:

```
public Dice()
    {
    for (int i = 1 ; i <= 3; i++) 
    {randomDieNum1 = ((int)(Math.random()* 100) % MAXVALUE1 + MINVALUE1);
    randomDieNum2 = ((int)(Math.random()* 100) % MAXVALUE2 + MINVALUE2);
    int total = randomDieNum1 + randomDieNum2;
        if (randomDieNum1 + randomDieNum2 == userNum)
        {result = randomDieNum1 + "+" + randomDieNum2 + "=" + total + "\n" +
                "You guessed the number correctly";
        ++ turns; //
         break; //stops the loop if condition is meet
         }

         else if(randomDieNum1 + randomDieNum2 != userNum)
        {
             result =  "You did not guess the \n number correctly\n\n";
             ++ turns;
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: You're missing a `{` at the end of your  `for (int i = 1 ; i <= 3; i++)`

Comment: You might have reconsider the logic used in the `if` condition

    if(x+y != c)
    {// do operation A}
    else if (x+y == c)
    {// do operation B}

the `else` condition will never get executed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from the missing `{` in `for (int i = 1 ; i <= 3; i++) {`

You might have to reconsider the logic used in the `if` condition

```
if(x+y != c)
{// do operation A}
else if (x+y == c)
{// do operation B}
```

the `else` condition after the `else-if` will never get executed.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't encapsulating everything in the loop

```
 for (int i = 1 ; i <= 3; i++)
```

You're missing the brackets for encapsulating

```
  for (int i = 1 ; i <= 3; i++) {

  }
```